# Why does my Apple Watch keep entering Power Reserve mode?

Tags: apple-watch

I updated to Watch OS3 last week, and now my Apple Watch keeps entering Power Reserve mode, even when I have plenty of power on it!  As it sits right now, I have 87% power, and it has already entered Power Reserve three or four times today!  I did not ask it to go there, and it has enough power.  Has anyone had this problem, and if so, how did you resolve it?

Comment: Isn't that the way watchOS is designed, to go into power-reserve mode whenever possible to preserve power?

Comment: @fsb Power Reserve is **not** the same thing as Low Power Mode on iPhones. In Power Reserve, it will only display the time, and the only way to exit out is to restart the watch. It's designed to only go on when there is around 1% battery left.

Comment: Thx @IronCraftMan, seems I was confused :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone (I don't recall who, and I'm surprised their comment isn't here - whoever you are, thanks!) suggested that it could be the Battery complication, which I really like for monitoring battery status.  However, when you touch it, it presents a big percentage display and a very large button that covers the bottom of the watch face; touching this button puts the watch in Power Reserve mode!

[image: Battery complication pop-up]

The problem is that I had the Battery complication at the bottom right, so two touches in that corner results in Power Reserve mode!  At first I thought I had to give up the Battery complication, but then I realized that by putting it in the upper left corner, I avoid the simple two touches in one corner; now, in order to put it in Reserve mode, you have to touch two distinct, separate areas.  It has now not gone into Reserve mode since then!

Of course, it would be even nicer to have a Battery complication that just shows the battery status, without causing this nasty behavior...

Comment: It's good that you were able to answer your question.  As as you can, please accept your answer.  This will help others who have the same issue as you.

Comment: Done - I was waiting for the one hour delay, and then a break from work!  ;)